# How to replace all tags with respective variables in R?

Tags: r, parsing, templates, tags

I have a template of the type:

```
template <- "Average: {{av}} \n Sum: {{sum}}"
inputs <- list(av = "15", sum = "100")
```

I need to replace all occurrences of `{{av}}` and `{{sum}}` with respective elements of `inputs`.

I tried:

```
gsub("\\{\\{(.+)\\}\\}", inputs["\\1"], template, perl = TRUE)
```

But it replaces all tags with "NULL".

How can I do the replacement correctly?

Answer (score 3):

an alternative to the previous solution :

```
for (i in names(inputs))
  regmatches(template,gregexpr(sprintf("\\{\\{%s\\}\\}", i), template)) <- inputs[[i]]
```

HTH

Comment: Very nice. How can I make it replace braces as well?

Comment: I've tried this: `regmatches(template,regexpr(sprintf("\{\{%s\}\}", i), template)) <- inputs[[i]]` but it seems not to produce the desirable result.

Comment: Much obliged. I noticed it replaces only the first occurrence of `{{sum}}`. Is it possible to replace all the occurrences?

Comment: yes, you just have to replace regexpr by gregexpr as edited now

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a loop.

```
template <- "Average: {{av}} \n Sum: {{sum}}"
inputs <- list(av = "15", sum = "100")
template.copy <- template



for (i in 1:length(inputs)) {
  x <- inputs[i]
  xn <- names(x)
  template.copy <- gsub(paste("\\{\\{", xn ,"\\}\\}", sep = ""), 
                        paste("\\{\\{", x, "\\}\\}", sep = ""), 
                        x = template.copy, perl = TRUE)
}

> template.copy
[1] "Average: {{15}} \n Sum: {{100}}"
```